# Is an application role active on a SQL server connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, application-role

How can i check, if an (and which) application role is active for a connection (DbConnection object) to the sql server?

My problem is, that all database objects have access granted for my application role, but when executing a select statement i get an "access denied" error. 
I use a single connection object with application role activated, but I fear, that either EntityFramework or the DI container creates another DbConnection object due to a configuration fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh. On re-reading the documentation for [sp_setapprole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188908.aspx), I see this sample code:

```
DECLARE @cookie varbinary(8000);
EXEC sp_setapprole 'Sales11', 'fdsd896#gfdbfdkjgh700mM'
    , @fCreateCookie = true, @cookie = @cookie OUTPUT;
-- The application role is now active.
SELECT USER_NAME();
-- This will return the name of the application role, Sales11.
```

So it would appear that accessing `USER_NAME()` will do the trick.

Comment: No chance to get the information w/o another statement execution? So that it can be seen in the debugger?

Comment: @okrumnow - Not so far as I'm aware, and I can't see a way to read it from another connection either (E.g. I was hoping it might show up in a DMV (e.g. `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, but I can't seem to find it anywhere)